# Windows 7 PC can't connect to NT4-style Samba domain anymore

Tags: windows-7, networking, samba

I have a Windows 7 PC connected to a Samba 3.5 domain controller that suddenly can't find the domain controller anymore. This worked for over a decade, and nothing changed in that network since then (and I know, it's old software, but that shouldn't matter). In an attempt to rejoin the network, it also keeps failing:

(sorry for the Dutch, but I think the errors are clear/familiar).

[image: Error joining domain]

> De domeinnaam S.....C kan een NetBIOS-domeinnaam zijn. Controleer, als
>   dit het geval is, of de domeinnaam juist bij WINS is geregistreerd.
>
> Als u zeker weet dat de naam geen NetBIOS-domeinnaam is, kan de
>   volgende informatie u bij het oplossen van het probleem met de
>   DNS-configuratie helpen.
>
> Er is een fout opgetreden bij het opvragen van de Service Location
>   (SRV)-bronrecord in DNS dat wordt gebruikt voor het vinden van een
>   Active Directory-domeincontroller (AD DC) voor het domein S.....C.
>
> De fout is: Geen records gevonden voor opgegeven DNS-query. (foutcode
>   0x0000251D DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)
>
> De query was voor de SRV-record van _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.S.....C

Google Translate version:

> 685/5000 The domain name S ..... C can be a NetBIOS domain name. If
>   this is the case, check whether the domain name is correctly
>   registered with WINS.
>
> If you are sure that the name is not a NetBIOS domain name, the following information can help you resolve the DNS configuration
>   issue.
>
> An error occurred while requesting the Service Location (SRV) resource record in DNS that is used to find an Active Directory domain
>   controller (AD DC) for the domain S ..... C.
>
> The error is: No records found for specified DNS query. (error code 0x0000251D DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)
>
> The query was for the SRV record of _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.S ..... C

The network has no DNS server that knows about the domain S.....C,
it's just Samba that broadcasts it. And Windows 7 LanMan is set to not
require DNS, and to use compatibility mode 1:

[image: LanMan registry settings]

I find it weird that when joining the domain, it's complaining about querying an SRV record. This was never necessary, and the LanMan registry settings are set not to.

The server's name (Butler) is broadcast over the network, because `nbtstat` and just Explorer can find it.

How do I debug this? How do I know whether it really doesn't see the broadcast domain name, or if it's using the wrong style domain controller?

Comment: Can you translate the Dutch? Also, it's abundantly clear the workstation is looking for an AD style domain which requires DNS records as evidenced by the lookup of the `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.S.....C` record.

Comment: Is it also abundantly clear _why_ it's looking for an AD style domain? `DNSNameResolutionRequired` and `DomainCompabilityMode` are set for NT4 style domains.

Comment: No, sorry, I'd post that answer if I knew it!